# How to Create a Bootstrap Modal that targets IE 9 and below Only

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a Modal using Bootstrap. However, I would like the modal to appear only for IE9 and below and not for any other browsers.

I figure I can do something like the following:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
//something here
<![endif]-->
```

The something part I don't know how I will call it from the modal.

How would I achieve that?

The following is the Modal and it is within a cfm file:

```
 <body id="#$.getTopID()#" class="#$.createCSSHook($.content('menuTitle'))#" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subnav" data-offset="50" onload="intialize();" class="modal-open">
    <!--- <cfinclude template="inc/navbar.cfm" /> --->
    <!--- Navbar's display below is set to absolute position --->
    <cfinclude template="inc/navbar_ap.cfm" />
    <div style="overflow-y:hidden;"
        <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false" style="display:block; padding-right:17px;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#d3d3d3">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-miss="modal">x</button>
                        <h3 class="modal-header" style="background-color:#d3d3d3">Attention</h3>                        
                    </div><!---Modal-Header Div--->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p style="text-align:center">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> to better experience this site.</p>
                    </div><!---Modal-Body Div--->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <p class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></p>
                    </div><!---Modal-Footer Div--->
                </div><!---Modal-Content Div--->
            </div><!---Custom Height Div--->
        </div><!---Modal Fade in Div--->
    </div><!---Start of Modal Div--->                   
    <!--End of Modal container-->
```

The following is the script for the modal to appear. Something simple:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
        $('##myModal').modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I notice that the close button and the x button on top does not close the modal. I am not sure what is wrong.

**UPDATE 2**

Still not able to resolve the issue.

```js
$(function(){
 $('##myModal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="overflow-y:hidden;">
         <div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false" style="display:block; padding-right:17px;">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:##428bca">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h3 class="modal-header" style="background-color:##428bca; text-align:center">Attention</h3>                        
                        </div><!---Modal-Header Div--->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <p style="text-align:center">You are using an outdated browser.<br /> <br /> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> to better experience this site.</p>
                        </div><!---Modal-Body Div--->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                         <p><a href="" class="btn btn-default btn pull-middle" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></p>
                        </div><!---Modal-Footer Div--->
                    </div><!---Modal-Content Div--->
                </div><!---Custom Height Div--->
            </div><!---Modal Fade in Div--->
        </div><!---Start of Modal Div--->   
  <!--End of Modal container-->

 <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

**UPDATE 3**

This is what I did:

Add the following in the head

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-min.css">
    <![endif]-->
```

This contains a the class which only appears in IE9 and below and that part works fine.

The issue I continue to have is that the modal bootstrap isn't working. The close button does not close but rather refreshes the page and directs it back to the home page where the modal pops up again.

Here is what I did. As you can see, ie-only css will not show in chrome or in firefox but will show in ie9 and below but the modal wont appear and when it did, the close and the x button on the top right would not work:

```js
$(function(){
 $('##myModal').modal('show');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ie-only" style="overflow-y:hidden;">
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false" style="display:block; padding-right:17px;">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:##428bca">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h3 class="modal-header" style="background-color:##428bca; text-align:center">Attention</h3>                        
                        </div><!---Modal-Header Div--->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <p style="text-align:center">You are using an outdated browser.<br /> <br /> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> to better experience this site.</p>
                        </div><!---Modal-Body Div--->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                         <p><a href="" class="btn btn-default btn pull-middle" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a></p>
                        </div><!---Modal-Footer Div--->
                    </div><!---Modal-Content Div--->
                </div><!---Custom Height Div--->
            </div><!---Modal Fade in Div--->
        </div><!---Start of Modal Div--->   
  <!--End of Modal container-->
```

Comment: cgi.http_user_agent will get you started.  Note that you will have to read this with coldfusion code, not javascript.

Comment: should be `data-dismiss`

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I have added data-dismiss and it still does not close the button or the button that contains x

Comment: @DanBracuk I am not very familiear with coldfusion. Hoping that the comment condition would be enough or maybe javascript

Comment: @DanBracuk questioin: Why not use the following '<!--[if lte IE 9]>
//something here
<![endif]-->'. Wouldn't that work? and then I would just add a class, call it ieOnly and display it in ie9 and hidden in other browsers?

Comment: You can't use conditional logic on a variable until you first assign a value to it.

Comment: @DanBracuk what do you mean by value?

Comment: @DanBracuk Do you mean assigning a class to the div. I did and it still does not work properly. I will post what I did

Comment: Considering that MSIE 9 has less than 4% usage globally, you should verify how many of your clients are still using it before you spend much more time on this. We still have a large client using it, but they're in the process of upgrading their machines. Hopefully, we'll end support for it by early next year.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno True, very true and that is why I would like a way to redirect the user to chrome/a page where they can upgrade to a better broswer. That being said, the conditional logic isnt working for me. Not sure why. I did the following: <!--[if lt IE 10]>
 .ie-only{display:block;} 
<![endif]-->
and the following:  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ie/ie.min.css">
<![endif]--> And for me, internally, they do not want to upgrade and it is quite disappointing